# React Router V6 - page is not in history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router v6. When I am on detail page and i´ll press arrow in chrome go on prev page it doesnt go on prev page but prev prev page. I checked history by long press on arrow back and the page I need is not there. How can i add that page to the history?
On the detail page i navigate from main page with **navigate('detailPage/key')**.

Edit: In detail page i did something like this, but then is not detail page in history.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => navigate('/mainPage');
  }, [navigate]);`
```

Comment: `navigate('/mainPage')` is still a PUSH action, pushing a new entry onto the history stack, so it should certainly be there. There's not enough context provided to provide any more help. Can you edit your post to include a [mcve] and better details for what exactly you are doing to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For react-router-v6

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

This '/mainPage' Page should be declared in App.js as a route.

```
  <Link to='/mainPage'><button>Go Main Page</button></Link>
```

You can check this link :https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8465

Comment: OMG... i replaced navigate() with <Link to={}> and it works...